# Laravel: get a model through another table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have gotten a model called User. in this model i have a function called UserActivity where i return this:

```
return $this->hasMany('App\UserActivity', 'userid');
```

After this i have a function that gets the activity name from the Activity table, but i do not know how to do this, i have currently gotten this:

```
public function Activity() {
      return $this->hasManyThrough('App\UserActivity', 'App\Activity', 'userid', 'activityid');
}
```

And in my view i want to use this like this:

```
$activiteiten = \App\User::find(Auth::user()->id);
dd($activiteiten->UserActivity()->Activity());
```

But then i get an error saying this:

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::Activity() (View: /var/www/vhosts/cpned.nl/intranet.cpned.nl/laravel/resources/views/dashboard.blade.php)
```

I can do it using inner joins but i am really wondering if i can do this with Laravel models. I do not know how currently, and because i don't know what the name is for the function in laravel i can't find it either, so I am sorry if this will be a duplicate.
My tables have the following keys and foreign keys:

Users: pk: id

user_activities: pk: userid, activityid

activities: pk: id

Thank you in advance!

Comment: make sure you are not getting any `NULL` UserActivity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading).

So something like:

```
$activiteiten = \App\User::with('UserActivity.Activity')->find(Auth::user()->id);
dd($activiteiten->UserActivity->Activity);
```

**Edit:** So then you can do something like this:

```
foreach($activiteiten->UserActivity as $user_activity) {
  foreach($user_activity->Activity as $activity) {
    print_r($activity);
  }
}
```

Shows how you can loop through the relationships.

Comment: Ok, now you have explained that, I have updated my answer. So you go through the models ```User->UserActivity->Activity```. There seems to be some inconsistencies in your question vs explanations but hopefully the updated answer helps.

Comment: It always returns the same like this:
"Property [UserActivity] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: /var/www/vhosts/cpned.nl/intranet.cpned.nl/laravel/resources/views/dashboard.blade.ph ▶"

and it is pointing at the dd($activiteiten->UserActivity->Activity); line

Comment: did you remove ```->get()``` from the query?

Comment: It now finally does a bit more then before but it still does not work, i get this error: Property [Activity] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: /var/www/vhosts/cpned.nl/intranet.cpned.nl/laravel/resources/views/dashboard.blade.php) 
In which file do i place the public function activity? In User.php, activity.php or the pivot table useractivity.php

Comment: With relation to my answer, it should go in useractivity.php

Comment: it turned out i had a relation set up wrong, but now i have it set up right but i only get the Activity table and no other data from the useractivity and the usertable?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159217/discussion-between-thimo-franken-and-cugreen).

Answer (score 1):

The `Activity` function should be in the User model. So then you can call it this way:

```
$activiteiten = \App\User::find(Auth::user()->id);
dd($activiteiten->Activity); //gives you a collection of activities
```

However, you need belongsToMany function rather than hasManyThrough since the relationship between users and activities is many-to-many.

This mean you cut down going through the Intermediate model. You can check the doc [on belongsToMany](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) to understand what to do better.

> A side note: Why are your functions name starting with capital letter?
>
> Also using hasMany relations should affect the function name as well, so that 'activity' becomes 'activities' (just to keep the functionality and interpretation in sync).

Update:

```
//User model

public function activities() {
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Activity', 'user_activity', 'userid', 'activityid');
}
```

This uses the 'user_activity' table, to find the relationship between users and activities, so that you may now access by `User::first()->activities` for example.

Comment: There is no direct relation between users and activities though, there is a pivot table that has the userid and the activityid, so the way you stated above does not work, does it? As far as the naming, thank you!

Comment: Yes, the pivot table is the connection between users and activities if I am correct, and using the example of relationship in the Laravel doc should be sufficient. Check my updated answer @ThimoFranken